# Automatically make the td in table equal depend on number of td

Tags: html, css, sass

I have several tables. Some have 4 td in a row, some have 3 td in a row. Is there any smart way to make those td equal depend on the number of td in a row, since I don't want to write a specific css for each case.

For example, if a row have 4 td, each td's width should be 25% and 33.33% if a row have 3 td.

I'm using scss.

Edit: I'm also looking for a way that also meet this condition too: in a table, there is two rows, the first row has 2 td, the second row has 3 td and this table still meet my requirement.

For example, in this case, I want the td in the first row (which has 1 td) will have 100% width, not 25%

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: use col merge option when you want to draw 3, column merge 2 columns into one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below CSS

```
  table {
     table-layout: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  td, th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     padding: 8px;
  }
```

Check Example here:- https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/yLyewjG

Comment: Thank you, but is there anyway else if I want to do something like: in a table, there is two rows, the first row has 2 td, the second row has 3 td and this table still meet my requirement?

Comment: Yes, it will work for all the requirements which you want.

Comment: Sorry, in this case, I want the td in the first row (which has 1 td) will have 100% width, not 25% https://codepen.io/Lincox/pen/vYELMmR

Comment: For this you need to write like this: <td colspan="4">1</td>

Comment: And if you want 3 td in 2nd row then use **colspan="3"**

Comment: Um, sorry, how about if there is 2 td in the first row, so td in the first row will be 50% width and td in the 2nd row will be 33.33% width. Use colspan in this case doesn't seem right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203951/discussion-between-luu-hoang-bac-and-aman).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a fixed table layout and set the width of the table. I have included a few examples below.

```css
.myTable, .subTable {
  width: 200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>1. table in a table(use a sub table that uses the same css)</h1>
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>apple pie</td>
    <td>orange tart</td>
    <td>blueberry crumble</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <table class="subTable">
      <tr>
        <td>apple pie</td>
        <td>orange chocolate</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <table class="subTable">
      <tr>
        <td>meat pie</td>
        <td>apple crumble</td>
        <td>cranberry jam</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
    
</table>

<hr>

<h1>2. use colspans that you will have to set via hand or javascript</h1>
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>pumpkin pie</td>
    <td>banana tart</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      blueberry pie
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there anyway else if I want to do something like: in a table, there is two rows, the first row has 2 td, the second row has 3 td and this table still meet my requirement?

Comment: As far as i know using only CSS to achieve this programmatically not possible. You have 2 choices as far as i can see. 1. is to use a table in a table(a new table in the row) 2. use colspans that you will have to set manually or with javascript. Please take a look at the above snippet for the update.